# Sustainsys Saml2 unhandled exception to browsing back to Idp

Tags: saml-2.0

I encountered an unhandled exception related to the absence of a cookie when the user logged in using the IdP. However, when the user clicked the browser's back button, it redirected them back to the IdP login page. After the user authorized on the IdP, they were redirected back to the '/saml2/acs' page, where the following error occurred.

**An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.**

> UnexpectedInResponseToException: Received message
> _a43b6a21-9367-4d6b-8034-7072144da19a contains unexpected InResponseTo "id29b1dcb436714da7be248bfaf38e5385". No cookie preserving state from
> the request was found so the message was not expected to have an
> InResponseTo attribute. This error typically occurs if the cookie set
> when doing SP-initiated sign on have been lost.

I aim to gracefully display errors to the user when they encounter issues with the IdP

> Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
>
> AADSTS750054: SAMLRequest or SAMLResponse must be present as query
> string parameters in HTTP request for SAML Redirect binding.